# Puppeteer: Wait until elementHandle is no longer attached to the DOM

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

So, I run into this problem where there are some spinners rendered here and there and I want to wait until the spinners are no longer attached in the DOM.

Don't know too much JS to do so, but in Selenium you can use a predicate like:

`Wait.Until(driver => driver.findElements(By.Xpath("XPATH")).Count < 0)`.

So far what I have accomplished is the following:

```
    async fillSearch(value: string) {
            await this.searchInput.then(x => x.click({ clickCount: 3 }));
            await this.page.keyboard.press("Backspace");
            await this.searchInput.then(x => x.type(value));
            ...//HERE I HAVE TO WAIT FOR THE SPINNER TO GO...
        }
```

`this.searchInput` is a `Promise<ElementHandle>` retrieved by `page.$x("xpathOfInput")`.

I have a prop called `this.spinners` retrieving a `Promise<ElementHandle[]>` so when the Promise it's resolved I can get the `lenght` of the array and know if any element was founded on the DOM.

So the question would be:

Is there a way to use something like `page.waitFor()` to wait for the promise to get resolved and afterwards compares if `spinners.length < 0` and wait until that happens?

I supose there must be a way to achieve the same with a predicate on the waitFor but so far I can't manage to pull it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using `page.waitForXPath`

The easiest way would be to use [`page.waitForXPath`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.0.1/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options) with the option `hidden` set to `true`:

```js
await page.waitForXPath('XPATH', { hidden: true });
```

This will wait until the element is not present in the DOM anymore or hidden (via CSS).

#### Alternative: `page.waitForFunction`

Alternatively, you can use [`page.waitForFunction`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.0.1/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args) to wait until a function that you provide returns true. By using [`document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) to evaluate an XPath expression you can then wait until your condition resoles to `true`.

#### Using an existing variable

As you already have the element in a variable, you can use [`page.waitForFunction`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.0.1/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args) and pass the element as `args`:

```js
await page.waitForFunction(element => element.parentNode === null, {}, spinnerElement);
```

You might need to change the checking function depending on how the node is removed.

Comment: Already look into it, but the thing is I already have the ElementHandler from the `page.$x()` function so the waitForXpath is no longer usable since it is encapsulated through page object model pattern . How would be the implementation for the waitForFunction if I already have an ElementHandle?

Comment: @FacuAlarcon I added a third way that covers that case.

Comment: works like a charm, also, I'll put here the sample because since I'm working dynamically with promises and element handlers have to adjust your code a little bit:



`await page.waitForFunction(element => element.ParentNode === null, {}, await this.inboxFeed.searchSpinner);`

Comment: Just wondering, what if the searchSpinner is an array like `ElementHande[]` can the function could be `element.lenght < 0` if I have to wait for every element to go away from the DOM?

Comment: @FacuAlarcon I don't think that is possible like that as the array would not automatically update.